# Special symbols in wysihtml5 editor

Tags: javascript, special-characters, html-entities, wysihtml5

I use [wysihtml5](http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/) editor on my site and I would like to have the following functionality - if user inserts text with special characters they are transformed to html entities.

For example, user inserts:

```
"Sample text, sample text, sample text ©"
```

I need to transform it to:

```
"Sample text, sample text, sample text &copy;"
```

I didn't find any information related to special symbols in editor docs. One of the method I think about is to create listener for paste event and process special characters at this step.

Could you advice what is the best way to add this functionality to the editor?

Comment: would changing it to an XML entity (ex `&#169;`) be acceptable? that's easy, but using named symbols will require a big list of conversions...

Comment: @dandavis yes, I think we could use decimal codes too

Answer (score 1):

you can use a RegExp character range to replace() them using a dynamic function:

```
strNew=strOld.replace(
  /([\u00A0-\u00FF])/g,  
  function(j,a){
             return "&#" + parseInt(a.charCodeAt(0), 16) + ";" ;
  }
);
```

live demo : http://pagedemos.com/27w7n4n58qpk

this could be applied from the string you get back from your editor, or i guess, on the innerHTML of the editor's contenteditable tag.